Problem to connect multiple docker-compose files
i'm running two different containers with docker and i'm using two docker-compose files.
These are the files:
webplatform:
version: '3.5'

services:
  b-datamanager:
    build:
      context: Backend/
      dockerfile: dataManager.containerfile
    image: b-datamanager:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - data:/data

  b-authenticationmanager:
    build:
      context: Backend/
      dockerfile: authenticationManager.containerfile
    image: b-authenticationmanager:latest
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - b-datamanager

  b-assetmanager:
    build:
      context: Backend/
      dockerfile: assetManager.containerfile
    image: b-assetmanager:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - b-datamanager

  b-applicationgateway:
    build:
      context: Backend/
      dockerfile: applicationGateway.containerfile
    image: b-applicationgateway:latest
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
      - int-net
    depends_on:
      - b-datamanager
      - b-authenticationmanager
      - b-assetmanager

  f-frontend:
    image: docker.io/library/nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - b-applicationgateway
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nginx/development.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        bind:
          propagation: rshared


networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
  int-net:
    external: true
    name: int-net


volumes:
  data:


asyncController:
version: '3.5'

services:
  b-middleware:
    build:
      context: Async-Backend
      dockerfile: middleware.containerfile
    image: b-middleware:latest
    ports:
      - "9096:9096"
    networks:
        - int-net
    volumes:
      - middleware_data:/middleware_data

networks:
  int-net:
    external: true
    name: int-net

volumes:
  middleware_data:


I need to let talk the b-applicationgateway and the b-middleware.
To do so, i created the network 'int-net' using
docker network create int-net

and then i just builed and runned my containers with the command
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up --build

for both the containers.
The containers are running and the internal network (backend and frontend) works, but, if i try to send an http request from the b-applicationgateway to the b-asynccontroller it give this exception:
[ApplicationGateway] [nio-9093-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
[Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: asynccontroller-b-middleware-1/172.27.0.2:9096] with root cause java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused

I also tried to run "docker network inspect int-net" and the containers are in the network
 {
        "Name": "int-net",
        "Id": "3908d6759fb18b06e5f945f05660e923515773ee27a495143d8a4bfea328922e",
        "Created": "2024-05-13T08:18:00.601493906Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2a3b5695e7a036c8e707e8ded301fd74655c6ef9da9cb7845e77c656fa9df051": {
                "Name": "asynccontroller-b-middleware-1",
                "EndpointID": "46e414ea3656331798459697a83625b93edf415295a08f29279c8a3db1b969ae",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b061c90f53b48085c39ec336cfdfc1e0b9d4f41147ab670696964a51df2819c5": {
                "Name": "webplatform-b-applicationgateway-1",
                "EndpointID": "b0581cdf767e99d15eb7408bebb5523d92c577e140d7abcfe4a6f13ccbcad738",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }


Someone have some suggestions? Thank you in advance!

From the error message, it looks like the DNS resolution is working, and so the Docker-level wiring is probably correct.  Is the b-middleware service actually listening on 0.0.0.0:9096 (in the process's code or configuration, independent of the Docker setup)?

I solved it, the problem was that i inserted the worng port in the b-middleware properties.... when i found it i was like crying ahah. Thanks anyway
